# Count total number of files in particular directory with specific extension

Tags: command-line, ls

I want to count the total number of files in particular directory that ends with ".mp4" extension.

I am getting following command:

```
ls -F |grep -v / | wc -l
```

It count all the files in particular directory, but I want the count of files that end with .mp4 extension.

Is there any Ubuntu command for that?

Comment: The simple, correct, straightforward answer is @louis-matthijssen one. `ls -1` handling of newline characters make, in this case, sensible to parse `ls` output. The marked one is wrong for the use of -R flag.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here you can do this way

```
ls -lR /path/to/dir/*.jpg | wc -l
```

This gives you count

Comment: Why the `-R`? Why doing a full `stat` when you just need the filename? Why not `ls -1 *.jpg| wc -l`? (ok, not working if you have filenames with newlines in it. In that case you deserve it ;-) ...)

Comment: This is for listing subdirectories recursively.

Comment: ...and the question was "counting the number of files in a directory". Moreover, this will list recursively *all content* of subdirectories *which name end in .jpg*, not files in subdirectories ending in `.jpg`. Have you ever tested it?

Comment: The question says "files in a specific directory", which implies that subdirectory recursion is not wanted.

Comment: This also fails if there are too many files in the directory (because `*.jpg` is expanded by the shell, not by `ls`) and if there are files whose names begin with hyphens.

Comment: @DavidRicherby This skips names that start with `.`. But it actually works okay with hyphens in names, except when `/path/to/dir` is the empty string or a relative path beginning with a hyphen. But **I was wrong before** to have said `ls` replaces characters with `?`. That happens when stdout is a terminal, but here the output is a pipe so `ls` sends all characters from filenames to `wc`. **That makes this answer wrong without the `-q` or `-b` flag to change that behavior**, because filenames can contain newlines. [l0b0's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/454568/22949) is free of these problems.

Comment: @sk1712 yes, but how do you put this into a bash script?

Comment: Despite all the negative comments, this worked for me, was much easier to follow, and was accepted by the person who originally asked the question. I'm finding it to be quite slow when there's a lot of files, and frustratingly much slower than "ls -1 | wc -l", but at least it works!

Answer (score 64):

Unfortunately this benign problem is difficult to solve in a way which supports all file names and is portable. [This](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/2bb1a09b41435ddb9961baaa5d7faa4e7e237a05/.bash_history#L240) is safe (it handles hidden files, paths containing spaces, dashes and even newlines) <strike>and POSIX compatible</strike>:

```
find /path/to/directory -mindepth 1 -type f -name "*.mp4" -printf x | wc -c
```

If you don't want it to be recursive, simply add `-maxdepth 1`.

[You shouldn't parse `ls` output.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Test:

```
$ cd -- "$(mktemp -d)"
$ touch -- -foo.mp4 .bar.mp4 .bat.mp4 'baz.mp4
> ban.mp4'
$ find . -mindepth 1 -type f -name "*.mp4" -exec printf x \; | wc -c
4
```

Compare with [the accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/454577/10371):

```
$ ls -lR ./*.mp4 | wc -l
3
```

Or other suggestions:

```
$ find . -name "*.mp4" | wc -l
5
$ ls -1 *.mp4 | wc -l
ls: invalid option -- '.'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
0
$ find . -name "*.mp4" | wc -c # Answer fixed at a later time
51
$ find . -name "*.mp4" | wc -l
5
$ find . | grep -i ".mp4$" | wc -l
5
$ ls . | grep ".mp4$" | wc -l
3
```

Comment: Although this answer is correct and robust, you can use `-printf x` instead of `-exec printf x \;`. That is: `find /path/to/directory -mindepth 1 -type f -name "*.mp4" -printf x | wc -c`  There's no need to `-exec` the external `printf` command, which if there are many files will be *very slow*, because `find` has to [fork(2)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man2/fork.2.html) off a copy of itself and then [execve(2)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man2/execve.2.html) `/usr/bin/printf`. With `-exec printf x \;`, that must be done once for *each file*.

Comment: [`-printf` is not supported in POSIX `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), which is why I didn't use it.

Comment: Neither are `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth`, which you used.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't picked up on that!

Comment: BSD `find` contains `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` but does not contain `-printf` so I do appreciate the inclusion of both.

Comment: fyi, this doesn't work on macOS, "-printf: unknown primary or operator"

Answer (score 29):

This one finds, sorts, and lists all files by extension in order:

```
find . -type f | sed 's/.*\.//' | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: Excellent! I just would add a `| sort -rn` at the end and maybe a `-mindepth 1` if just current dir.

Comment: And maybe pipe to `head -n` to get the top n.

Comment: I had to add another `| sort` and added `-maxdepth 1` for myself

Comment: This is great! To also count filename without extension, I ended up with `find . -type f -printf '%f\n' | sed --regexp-extended 's/(^.*\.)|(^[^.]*$)//' | sort | uniq --count | sort --numeric-sort --reverse`

Answer (score 15):

I think it's very simple as following commands.

```
$ find . -name "*.mp4" | wc -l
8
```

or

```
$ find . | grep -i ".mp4$" | wc -l
8
```

I think that above commands calculate count of files and directories names `*.mp4`

so I suggest you use `-type f` option as `find` parameter as following.

```
$ find . -name "*.mp4" -type f | wc -l
8
```

In addition, `ls -lR` can be used as `find .`

Answer (score 4):

You could use `ls -1 *.mp4 | wc -l`.

This will list all files ending on `.mp4`, printing each file on a new line (`ls -1 *.mp4`), pipe the output to `wc` which will count the number of new lines using the `-l` flag.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, it works

Comment: Since `*.mp4` is expanded by the shell, not `ls`, this will fail if there are so many `.mp4` files in the directory that the list of them can't be passed to `ls` as arguments.

Comment: @Rmana Test it in a directory containing a file called `--.mp4`

Comment: @DavidRicherby yes, you are right. `--` will solve the second case; the former will rise an error message (you need a lot of files!) and another nice question here. Corner cases, but worth noticing, yes.

Comment: @Rmano Without adding `-q` or `-b`, this does *not* tolerate newlines in filenames. If you run `ls -1 *.mp4` from your terminal with no pipe, `ls` sees its [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) is a terminal and takes `-q` as implied, printing `?`s. But that behavior goes away when the output is piped. `ls -1 *.mp4 | wc -l` overcounts if there are newlines. `ls -1 *.mp4 | cat` shows what `wc` "sees." (Similarly, `-1` is implied when stdout *isn't* a terminal, so it's optional.) `ls -1q -- *.mp4 | wc -l` almost works, but not with zero .mp4 files.

Answer (score 3):

This should give you the list of file with .mp4

```
ls /path/to/directory | grep ".mp4$"
```

When combined with `wc -l` will give you count

```
ls /path/to/directory | grep ".mp4$" | wc -l
```

if you want search to include subdirectories

```
ls -lR /path/to/directory | grep ".mp4$" | wc -l
```

Comment: does not give a count

Comment: gave it to me when used with `wc -l`

Comment: use ls without piping to grep and shorten your answer. It has been posted at least twice now.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen `ls /directory/*.mp4` causes the shell to expand the glob and execute something like `ls /directory/file1.mp4 /directory/file2.mp4 ...` This will fail if the directory contains more mp4 files than can be passed as arguments to `ls`.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - it is not my ls command , I use find ;)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen In your comment, you said to "use ls without piping to grep". What did you mean, if you didn't mean `ls -lR /path/*.mp4`?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I mean there is no need to pipe to grep

Comment: @bodhi.zazen If you do `ls /path/ | wc -l`, you'll count all files, not just the mp4 files (and potentially fail for files containing newlines, depending on the behaviour of `ls`).

Comment: The methods given in this answer are extremely brittle and often count wrong. *[a]* Without `-q` or `-b`, newlines in filenames are piped literally to `grep`, as `-q` is only implied when [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) is a terminal. (Use `ls /path/to/directory | cat` to check what `grep` sees.) *[b]* `.` in a regex matches *any* character, not just `.`, so names like `abcmp4` are matched. (`\.` or `[.]` would avoid this.) *[c]* `ls -l` shows symlink targets, so you may get `foo -> /path/to/file.mp4` and `foo` will be counted as an `.mp4`.

Answer (score 2):

Check [How To Count The Files By Extension In Linux?](https://www.2daygeek.com/how-to-count-files-by-extension-in-linux/), it gives a good answer and explanation, you can use the following command:

```
find . -type f | sed -n 's/..*\.//p' | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always just use a for loop, which I think has the advantage of not requiring you to remember the flags of several different commands.

For example:

```
a=0; for i in ./*.jpg; do a=$(expr  $a + 1); done; echo $a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ls | grep --count \.csv$
```

Replace (.csv with the extension you want)

Explanation: I think that a simple scheme is to fetch the list of files, and count the extension with grep. `\.` to match `.` and `$` to match the extension at the end of line. It works because when the output of ls is piped, one file name is sent per line, which you can verify by running:

```
ls | cat
```

Comment: Note that instead of `grep --count`, you could also use `grep -c`.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, one cold resort to using arrays with glob:

```
$ files=( *.mp4  )
$ echo ${#files[@]}
30
```