# terminal - count how many types of (file) extensions exist with their associated files in current directory

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I've about 0.1 million images in a directory with all kinds of extensions (gif, jpeg, png, tiff, etc).

Now I want to find out how many types (of extensions) are there in the current directory, possibly with total number of images associated with them using a terminal command, something like this:

```
some-command

png  - 11010
jpeg - 1134
jpg  - 145
tiff - 555
```

P.S: I do not want to count files with specific extension but rather want to count types of extensions with their associated files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count total number of files in particular directory with specific extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454564/count-total-number-of-files-in-particular-directory-with-specific-extension)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18506/recursive-statistics-on-file-types-in-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplicate candidate (deep down) has a close answer. Here it is modified:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sed 's/.*\.//' | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: One problem here. It's also finding files in sub-directories and I neither wish to count files in them nor want to move them because there's a lot of images in them. And I'll be grateful if you can tell what this command is doing so that I can exploit it in my way if I want to

Comment: I've added max depth to the find command.